# Cucumber CLI - get more information about execution

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm running test based on [run-cucumber-tests-from-cli](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/) and except getting the status code from the execution, is there a way to view the test output or any other data related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command line option `--plugin pretty` to get more output. You can also use `--help` to see more information about other available options and plugins.